# contains(@title,'®') looks not working due to special character

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML node something like below -

```
<url title="Take the STARPLUS® for entertaiment" depth="2" is_external="False"/>
```

Now in XSLT in am writing code something like below -

```
<xsl:when test="contains(@title,'®')">

<!-- Make registration mark super scripted-->
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
</xsl:otherwise>     
</xsl:choose>
```

Here `contains(@title,'®')` looks not working due to special character.

Could somebody help me to write this XSLT check.

**NOTE-** i can not do encoding or escaping in XML as it is already in place in the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That test should work just fine. You could try using an entity reference instead:

```
contains(@title,'&#174;')
```

Here's an example of both matching correctly.

**XML Input**

```
<url title="Take the STARPLUS® for entertaiment" depth="2" is_external="False"/>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="url">
        <xsl:if test="contains(@title,'®')">
            <has_reg><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></has_reg>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(@title,'&#174;')">
            <has_reg><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></has_reg>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<has_reg>Take the STARPLUS® for entertaiment</has_reg>
<has_reg>Take the STARPLUS® for entertaiment</has_reg>
```

Comment: Yes , Deniel , i do'nt know why test="contains(@title,'®') is not working in my case. But contains(@title,'&#174;') working :-) Thanks a lot for your quick answer.